# How can I install Windows 7(64) after having already installed Ubuntu(64) ? The Windows install manager says it can't install on a GPT drive

Tags: windows-7, gpt

I installed Ubuntu(64) on a partition of my 1TB drive. I left 200gb formatted on NTFS to install Windows 7(64) later and 600gb of free space. When I get to the part of selecting the partition to install Win7 it says it's not possible to install it on a GPT drive. I just finished building the PC today so the first thing I installed was Ubuntu. Can anybody help me with this ?

edit: It seems that it's relevant whether the system is UEFI or not. My mobo is UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 can only boot on GPT drives if the computer is running UEFI, make sure your motherboards UEFI isn't running in legacy CPM (BIOS Compatibility Mode For Legacy OSs). If your hardware is very new it likely uses the new revision of UEFI that Windows 8 is designed for, alas Windows 7 uses on older revision and will not boot on systems that have the new revision of UEFI. Alternatively you can format your hard drive as MBR and set your UEFI to function in legacy CPM mode (BIOS), then reinstall Ubuntu and Windows 7 happily.

The other possibility is that if you did not create an FAT32 (EFI BOOT) partition, that could alternatively be causing the problem, as windows requires that parition for writing EFI boot information to rather than an MBR Boot sector, you can create this parition yourself from ubuntu, just make sure to flag it as boot and place it as the 1st parition on the drive. Windows also sometimes gets pissy if you don't let it create an MSR partition.

You should start entering your UEFI and checking the settings to see if it's running in CPM mode or not.

Once you make sure it's not running in CPM mode then erase your hard drive, Install windows 7, then shrink the windows partition using Gparted on an Ubuntu live cd, then install ubuntu in the free space.

Comment: Thanks mango. I'll just set it to MBR and install Win7 first and then Ubuntu. This UEFI thingy is being too much of a hassle.

Comment: [CPM = Control Program for Microcomputers,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp/m) an early-1980s OS. I believe you mean the Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which provides BIOS-compatibility to an EFI -- but even then, you're off in some details. Most importantly Windows 7 *will* boot on recent EFIs, although it needs to have Secure Boot disabled to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Windows 7 in EFI mode requires booting the boot disc in EFI mode. This can be tricky sometimes, but it is possible. You may need to use your firmware's built-in boot manager (usually accessible by pressing Esc or some random function key early in the boot process) and selecting the boot option for the boot medium that includes the string "EFI" or "UEFI". There are lots of Web sites that go into more detail about this, such as [this one.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2011/05/31/installing-windows-7-on-uefi-based-computer.aspx) (Try a Web search for more; that one was just the first site that came up when I did such a search.)

Before you do anything, though, it's imperative that you [determine your Linux boot mode.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html#linux) If Linux is booting in EFI/UEFI mode, you should try to install Windows in EFI/UEFI mode. If Linux is booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, though, you've got a dilemma, because Windows won't install in this mode to a GPT disk, although Linux will. Thus, you'll need to decide whether to [convert your disk from GPT to MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html#gpt2mbr) to accommodate a BIOS-mode boot of both OSes or to [install an EFI boot loader for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders) so as to let both OSes boot from the GPT disk in EFI mode.